# How can I make this header perfectly aligned?

Tags: html, css, header

I am using the following header design, which should take over the top part of the page 100% horizontally but in some browsers on the right hand side it wouldn't cover it.

How can i fix this?

HTML:

```
 <header id="loop">
 <img src="/images/logo.png" height="50px" />
 </header>
```

CSS:

```
 background-color: #990000;
 height: 85px;
 margin-left: -8px;
 margin-top: -8px;
 position: relative;
 width: 101.3%;
```

Comment: @sheikhheera I did 101.3% to cover the entire area.  If i do 100% it wouldn't cover the area.

Comment: `margin-left: -8px;` is not a good way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit hard to tell with no solid example.

Make sure that the body/header margin values:

```
body { margin: 0; }
```

Also, remove the width value you put in your css and reset your margins. Your CSS should be:

```
background-color: #990000;
height: 85px;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your negative margin-left of 8px and the width of 101.3%. That fills the full width only when the screen width is more than 615px.

The best option is to get rid og the margin and use a width of 100%.